# Signal handler only handling first instance of a segfault

Tags: c

This is my signal handler:

```
void sig_segv_handler(int sig) 
{
  printf("This is the signal handler for SIGSEGV\n");

  (void) signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_IGN);

  siglongjmp(env, 1);   

}
```

My main() function:

```
int main() {

  (void) signal(SIGSEGV, sig_segv_handler);

  char * pattern = "a";
  unsigned int patlength = 1;
  struct patmatch *locations;
  unsigned int loclength = 5;

  findpattern(pattern, patlength, locations, loclength);

  return 0;

}
```

And my findpattern() function:

```
unsigned int findpattern(unsigned char *pattern, unsigned int patlength, struct patmatch *locations, unsigned int loclength) {
     for (i=0; i<max; i++) {

     j = sigsetjmp(env, 1);

     temp = (char *) i;

   printf("temp = %c\n", *temp);
  }
}
```

Through extensive testing thanks to the use of printf() calls, I know that the program crashes on the printf("temp = %c\n", *temp);.  The first time this happens, my signal handler is called and runs normally (it prints out "this is the signal handler"), but the second time I get a segfault my program crashes and complains about a segfault.  Why does it correctly get handled the first time but not the second time and beyond?

Comment: Because you remove your handler with `signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_IGN);`

Comment: Are you _just_ trying to debug your program? If so, running under `gdb` might be easier. To fix the cause of the segfault: `temp = (char *) i;` --> `temp = (char *) &i`. But ... this still won't do much good as even the fixed construct isn't that useful unless `i` is defined as `char i` (i.e. it _might_ work on little-endian machines, but it's a hack at best). And, outputting binary to a terminal also isn't a good thing either. Why don't you post your _entire_ code as it's hard to suggest something better without more context.

Comment: Thank you Barmar- that solved it :D